# Clear variables before leaving activity for not having their last values when I go back on it

Tags: android, android-activity

My App has 3 Activities A, B and C

The Classical Way is: 
from A to B to A (startActivityForResult(intent) to C (startActivity(intent))

On C, 
I can go back to A (startActivity(intent)), but when I go again on C (always with the same way A > B > A > C) one of the variable has still the value it had when I quit activity C the last time.

In fact, a lot of the state is remembered, but I want to clear it all

The variable is an integer initialized to 0 and incremented during the activity. But it keeps the last value it had and that causes a crash. I can put his value to 0 before go to A with an Intent, but I think this is not the best way to do.

How could I do to clear C before quit ?

Excuse me for my very poor english, it's very difficult to explain my problem...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In activity C, override the onNewIntent() method and then use it to reinitialize your variables. The onNewIntent() method is called whenever an existing instance of an activity is brought to the foreground by a new intent, as is the case in your app.

Edit: You may need to make activity C a singleTop activity for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new with Android, can you give me some code for example ? What i understood: put 'android:launchMode="singleTop"' on the manifest and called C with newIntent().... Thanks for advance

Comment: i just noticed that only the static variables are not reinitialized, not the others....